# the problem of "using Shared = std::shared_ptr<>" in base class and child class

Tags: c++, c++11, shared-ptr, using

I just solve a bug caused by "using Shared" in base class and child class. Like this:

```
class B: public A {
public:
    /**
     * Attention! This "using Shared" should be located before "using ResCallback " because
     * in class A, there is also a "using Shared".
     */
    using Shared = std::shared_ptr<B>;

    using ResCallback = std::function<void(const C& c, const char* data, size_t size, Shared b)>;
```

In the other file, there is class A:

```
class A {
public:
    using Shared = std::shared_ptr<A>;
```

In the past, I put "using ResCallback" before "using Shared" then it caused problem. This makes me doubt the "using Shared". Is there a better design style to avoid this bug source?

Comment: Just use `std::shared_ptr<B>` directly instead...? Or `B::Shared`?

Comment: Have to declare before you can use.  It would have been nice if the language allowed things to be in any order, and some other languages are like that.  But not C++, and that won't be changing.

Comment: DRY -- consider CRTP if you have this kind of boilerplate.

Answer (score 1):

Having the same type name in a base class and a derived class, but referring to different types, is a potential source of problems, as you have seen.

I would avoid having the same name (`Shared`) in both classes.

I tend to have `APtr` and `BPtr` as type aliases in the same namespace as `A` and `B` respectively, and just use `std::shared_ptr<A>` inside the `A` class, and `std::shared_ptr<B>` inside the `B` class.

If you really like the `X::Shared` pattern for `std::shared_ptr<X>`, then you need to consistently make it the first declaration in the class definition, and then it avoids the potential for breakage like you are seeing here.